# Generic messages are displayed instead of messages specific to the constraints

Tags: sapui5

For an input field with constraints of `minLength: 2` and `maxLength: 10` symbols, if you were to introduce 11 symbols, you are going to get a static error message that it is an "Invalid entry".

The following `Input` field:

```xml
<Input value="{
  path: 'modelExample>/Example1',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
  constraints: {
    minLength: 2,
    maxLength: 10
  }
}"/>
```

How to modify Input field, so that the error message is changed to: "Your input can only be between 2 and max 10 symbols"?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere you must be setting the `valueState` manually, hence the generic error message.

Here you can see more specific messages depending on the input value:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
], async (XMLView, JSONModel, Core) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      core:require="{
        StringType: 'sap/ui/model/type/String'
      }"
    >
      <App>
        <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
          <Input
            width="17rem"
            showClearIcon="true"
            value="{
              path: '/myModelValue',
              type: 'StringType',
              constraints: {
                minLength: 2,
                maxLength: 10
              }
            }"
          />
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: new JSONModel({ myModelValue: "Alice" }),
    height: "100%",
  });

  Core.getMessageManager().registerObject(control, true);
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

- [image: UI5 input validation min length message]
- [image: UI5 input validation max length message]

Cf. documentation topic [**Validation Messages**](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7) section "Automatically Created Messages". Most of the times, setting `"handleValidation": true` to the `"sap.ui5"` section in `manifest.json` is sufficient to enable generating meaningful messages automatically.