# Additional ways of letting SAPUI5 generate messages?

Tags: sapui5

One way of creating validation error messages, in this case from Input's `minLength` & `maxLength` ...

```xml
<Input
  placeholder="Enter name"
  valueStateText="Error Text."
  value="{
    path: '/firstName',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
    constraints: {
      minLength: 1,
      maxLength: 10
    }
  }"
/>
```

..., is to register the control or view beforehand via `MessageManager`:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().registerObject(oView, true);
```

Is there a way of automatically generating [`constraint` specific messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67901432/5846045) **without using `MessageManager`?**

If there isn't a way, how is it usually done? Are all views registered in the `Component.js` or  each view's `onInit` has a `MessageManager` section as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable the automatic message generation in the application descriptor (`manifest.json`) section `/sap.ui5/handleValidation` as mentioned in the documentation **topic [Validation Messages](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7)**.

```json
{
  "sap.ui5": {
    "handleValidation": true
  }
}
```

### `handleValidation`

> Possible values: `true` or `false` (default); used to enable or disable validation handling by the message manager for this component, see [Error, Warning, and Info Messages](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/62b1481d3e084cb49dd30956d183c6a0.html).

Source: [Descriptor for Applications, Components, and Libraries (manifest.json)](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da)

Demo: [https://embed.plnkr.co/L0ADaEBKvexsrrKk](https://embed.plnkr.co/L0ADaEBKvexsrrKk?show=manifest.json,view%2FApp.view.xml,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)

Comment: Thank You for your answer! Tried out didn't work. Besides changing the value of "handleValidation", is it required to do something additional ?

Comment: @Roman I enhanced my answer with a demo. Works well there

Comment: Thank you for your example! It seemingly does work in your example, however it still doesn't in mine, i use OpenUI5 instead of SAPUI5, maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Roman The sample is also running with OpenUI5 not SAPUI5. Please share more code so that we can figure out why it's not working in your case